# mustache engine not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am using node.js

I want to render data into a html file from my server.js file.But there was an error....Can I render that data into html directly from server.js using {{}} this mustache tag?

```
var express = require('express');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');
var mustache = require('mustache'); 

var mustacheExpress = require('mustache-express');
var app = express();
```

how to change ejs to mustache?

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'webapps')));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
var apiURL = 'http://10.0.0.244:9002';

app.listen(9002, function(req, res) {
    console.log("mustache server is running");
});
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {

    res.render('customers/list.html');

});
```

I want to render data using mustache in this file ?

```
app.get('/team', function(req, res) {
    request(apiURL + 'getteams?teamID='+req.query.teamID, 
function(error,response,body){
        response = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        res.render('customers/partials/next.html',{ 
            status: response.status,
            team: response.list
        });

    }); 
 });
```

When I am compiling I got below error:

```
undefined:1
undefined
^

Syntax Error: Unexpected token u
```

But I have already tried below code .that also not working:

```
var mustacheExpress = require('mustache-express');
app.engine('html', mustacheExpress());
app.set('view engine', 'mustache');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); 
app.get('/', function (req, res) {       
res.render('a');
});
```

Comment: please add some details - is it Node or something custom?

Comment: Sorry for that....I am using Node.js